# Django 1.5 query that includes columns from other models

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I wish to include in my query, columns from other tables. 
I wish to include all columns from reports and the name columns from Product and Manufacturer in my output.

My current query looks like this:

```
latest = Report.objects.values('date').latest('date')['date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`]
rows = Report.objects.filter(date=latest).order_by('platform')
```

--

```
#
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(blank=False,null=False,unique=True,max_length=100)
comment = models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=200)
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.name

#
class Product(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(blank=False,null=False,unique=True,max_length=100)
manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer,related_name="products",null=True,blank=True)
comment = models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=200)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.name

#
class Part(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(blank=False,null=False,unique=True,max_length=100)
product = models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name="parts",null=True,blank=True)
comment = models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=200)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.name

#
class Platform(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(blank=False,null=False,unique=True,max_length=100)
comment = models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=200)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.name

#
class Report(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
part = models.ForeignKey(Part,related_name="reports")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to include those elements **in** your QuerySet. In fact, you already have them : you just need to retrieve **related objects**.

With your code, **latest** and **rows** are querysets on **Report** model which have a foreign key on **Part** model

```
# in any *.py files, such as views.py
for report in rows:
    # You can access the Part object, so you can access Product, 
    # so you can access Manufacturer, just by hooking through the reverse relationship
    product_name = report.part.product.name
    manufacturer_name = report.part.product.manufacturer.name
```

You can access those element from your templates too :

```
# in your template.html
{% for report in rows %}
<p>Part: <span>{{ report.part }}</span></p>
<p>Product: <span>{{ report.part.product.name }}</span></p>
<p>Manufacturer: <span>{{ report.part.product.manufacturer.name }}</span></p>
```

So as you can see, everything is already ship with your queryset.

Comment: Exactly what I needed .... putting row.part.product.name / row.part.product.manufacturer.name in the template is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the product and manufacturer name for a report by using `report.part.product.name` and `report.part.product.manufacturer.name`.

So you could do (using your current query):

```
for report in rows:
    product_name = report.part.product.name
    manufacturer_name = report.part.product.manufacturer.name
```

There are better ways to do it, but it depends on what you want to do with the names so you'll need to be a bit more specific if you want help there. If you do end up using a simple for loop like that you probably want to have a look at [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to avoid firing off extra queries for every report in `rows`.